# Change image of a button that is on an element of a LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have this longListSelector:

```
          <phone:LongListSelector
                        x:Name="ListaMensajesTablon"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Mensajes}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MensajesTablonDataTemplate}"
                        SelectionChanged="MensajeTablonSelected"/>
```

With this ItemTemplate:

```
       <DataTemplate x:Key="MensajesTablonDataTemplate">
          <Grid>
              <Button MaxHeight="85" MaxWidth="95" MinHeight="85" MinWidth="95" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Click="Button_Click" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Image x:Name="imagenFav" MaxHeight="75" MaxWidth="75" MinHeight="75" MinWidth="75" 
                                   Source="{Binding userFav, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHeart}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Button.Content>
              </Button>
          </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
```

This code-behind:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        botonFavPulsado = true;
        botonAmor = (Button)sender;
    }


    private void MensajeTablonSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(botonFavPulsado)
        {                
            var myItem = ((LongListSelector)sender).SelectedItem as MensajeTablon;

            if(botonAmor!=null)
            {
                if (myItem.userFav)
                {
                    botonAmor.Content = new Image
                        {
                            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("icons/heart.red.png", UriKind.Relative))
                        };
                }
                else
                {
                    botonAmor.Content = new Image
                    {
                        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("icons/heart.white.png", UriKind.Relative))
                    };
                }
            }
            botonFavPulsado = false;

          }
        }
```

I want to do is that when you press a button that is inside an element of LongListSelector change the picture . The first time I press the button enters in the  function  Button_Click and then enters in the function MensajeTablonSelected function and change the image (good). The problem is the second time I press the same button is entering in the function Button_Click function and does not enter in the function MensajeTablonSelected

Resume : ToggleButton in LongItemSelector working the first time but not the second one

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
 private void MensajeTablonSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    if (((LongListSelector)sender).SelectedItem != null)
    if(botonFavPulsado)
    {                
        var myItem = ((LongListSelector)sender).SelectedItem as MensajeTablon;

        if(botonAmor!=null)
        {
            if (myItem.userFav)
            {
                botonAmor.Content = new Image
                    {
                        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("icons/heart.red.png", UriKind.Relative))
                    };
            }
            else
            {
                botonAmor.Content = new Image
                {
                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("icons/heart.white.png", UriKind.Relative))
                };
            }
        }
        botonFavPulsado = false;
        //Unselect ITEM
        ((LongListSelector)sender).SelectedItem = null;
      }
    }
```

This solution have a problem, the function MensajeTablonSelected is called again.

Comment: It gets called twice because at the end you change the selected item again.  Once for the click, and once for click -> null.